# JS works in FF but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, doctype

i'm new into JS. I have done 2 simple functions to change value and onclick-event for an input-button.

```
function doAjaxRequest(url, divID, buttonID) {
  $(divID).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />');
  setTimeout(function(){ $(divID).load(url); }, 600);
  setTimeout(function(){ $(buttonID).attr({
      value: 'Schliessen',
      onClick: 'clear_div(\''+url+'\', '+divID.id+', '+buttonID.id+')'
    });}, 600);
};

function clear_div(url, divID, buttonID) {
    $(divID).empty();
    $(buttonID).attr({
      value: 'Mehr...',
      onClick: 'doAjaxRequest(\''+url+'\', '+divID.id+', '+buttonID.id+')'
    });
};
```

functions call is

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<input type="button" id="button1" onClick="doAjaxRequest('test.html', div1, button1);" value="More..."/>
```

the doctype i'm using for my homepage is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

the functions both work correctly in IE but in FF they only work if i set the doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
```

i also tryed the "loose.dtd" with no effect.

What am i doing wrong with JS?
Hope someone can help me.

Greets
Joe

Comment: Have you tried changing `onClick` to `onclick`

Comment: Title: *"JS works in FF but not in IE"* Body: *"...the functions both work correctly in IE but in FF they only work if..." Which is correct?

Comment: In Q.title: _works in FF but not in IE_, in Q.text _work correctly in IE but in FF ..._ ?

Comment: Tell us which version of Internet Explorer are you using. Most of them are deprecated and do not follow many standards, so it may be something important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably that `onClick` should be `onclick` (case is significant in attributes in XHTML). But there are a couple of problems.

1. In your markup here:

   ```
   <input type="button" id="button1" onClick="doAjaxRequest('test.html', div1, button1);" value="More..."/>
   ```

   You haven't put quotes around `div1` or `button1`, which means you're relying on the browser dumping those symbols in the global namespace because they're the IDs of your elements. That's fairly common (IE and some others do it), but it's not universal. Instead, I'd pass strings and then look them up properly.
2. Since you're using jQuery, there's no reason to (and several reasons not to) use `onclick` attributes.

   So:

   ```
   function doAjaxRequest(url, divID, buttonID) {
     $('#' + divID).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />');
     setTimeout(function(){
       $('#' + divID).load(url);
     }, 600);
     setTimeout(function(){
       $('#' + buttonID)
         .attr({value: 'Schliessen'})
         .click(function() {
           clear_div(url, divID, buttonID);
       });
     }, 600);
   }

   function clear_div(url, divID, buttonID) {
       $('#' + divID).empty();
       $('#' + buttonID)
         .attr({value: 'Mehr...'})
         .unbind('click')
         .click(function() {
           doAjaxRequest(url, divID, buttonID);
         });
   }
   ```

   And similarly, your button hookup originally should be:

   ```
   $("#button1").click(function() {
     doAjaxRequest('test.html', 'div1', 'button1');
   });
   ```

   ...rather than using the `onclick` in the HTML. That code needs to appear *after* the button in the HTML (it's fairly common to recommend putting `script` tags at the *bottom* of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag), or you can wrap it in a jQuery `ready` handler:

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       $("#button1").click(function() {
         doAjaxRequest('test.html', 'div1', 'button1');
       });
   });
   ```

   ...so it runs only when the DOM has loaded.

Notes:

- Now we're using real functions for the event handlers, and hooking them up in a modern way.
- We're using the IDs of the elements, not the global instances of them (which aren't entirely reliable).
- We're using `unbind` to remove all previous `click` handlers before adding our new one.
- There's no need for a semicolon after a function declaration. Semicolons terminate statements. Function declarations aren't statements (they're declarations). That said, putting a semicolon there is harmless. :-)

And finally: Rather than removing the old `click` handler and putting in a new one, I think I'd probably just have the click handler change its behavior based on some flag.

Comment: +1 Good answer, even though I am not sure if it fixes the problem OP had.

Comment: @Tadeck: Thanks. The XHTML vs. HTML thing in FF should be caused by the `onClick` vs. `onclick` I mentioned up top (it **must** be all lower case in XHTML; in HTML it can be anything you like, even `OncLiCk`). Most of the rest of it is just better practices. :-)

Comment: Ok, now it is clear to me :) Doctype + attributes' cases were the core of the issue here. Thanks.

Comment: thank you, for your well explained answer. I'll try this and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but your parameters to doAjaxRequest look funny to me, in the following way: I'm not sure all browsers expose an element as a global variable named after the id of the element. I'd be more sure that your code was correct if you did it like this:

```
onClick="doAjaxRequest('test.html', '#div1', '#button1');"
```

Comment: I was thinking the same. Better to send the IDs, instead of referring to the object.

Comment: Still issues with the call to `clear_div`, and that alone won't help with the `onClick` / `onclick` issue, AND using dynamically-generated `onclick` strings is just a Bad Idea (esp. when the page is already using jQuery, so it's trivially easy to do it correctly).